# LIKE search in bytea datatype (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, bytea

Table:

```
\d blob

 Column  |       Type   | Collation |                 Default                  
---------+--------------+-----------+------------------------------------------
 id      | integer      |           | nextval('modlink_blob_id_seq'::regclass)
 content | bytea        |           |
```

This statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) "job" INNER JOIN "blob" ON ("job"."input_id" = "blob"."id")
  WHERE UPPER("blob"."content"::text) LIKE UPPER('%csv%');
```

Error message:

```
ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 1989028364
```

What can I do to make this statement not fail?

Comment: Why are you storing text data in a `bytea` column? That makes no sense. A `text` column would be a lot easier to deal with

Comment: In my case the bytea columns contain plain http requests. They are mostly text, but sometimes they contain binary data. AFAIK a text column can't be used for this, but may there is a different and better solution. If you know one, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use *position* function https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-binarystring.html

```
WHERE position('csv'::bytea in "blob"."content") > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way i found to make 'LIKE' search in PostgreSQL in columns with a lot of content was using tsvector columns.

One advantages is more fast than make 'like' searches and allow create index.

The boring part is create a trigger to replicate the content in a new column.

The article below shows how to use tsvector.

http://rachbelaid.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/

```
Column  |       Type   | Collation |                 Default                  
---------+--------------+-----------+------------------------------------------
 id      | integer      |           | nextval('modlink_blob_id_seq'::regclass)
 content | bytea        |           |
 search  | tsvector     |           |
```

This is the SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "job" INNER JOIN "blob" ON ("job"."input_id" = "blob"."id") 
WHERE blob.search @@ plainto_tsquery('csv');
```

A observation: I use `text` columns instead `bytea`.

Comment: you could setup `search` as a `generate stored` column, right?